# ValueMember of ListBox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Good day,

I would like to display the phone numbers from my table "Subscribers" with the same value (as string) associated with it. For instance, I would like to display these numbers:

```
+12345678 
+87654321
```

Here is my code:

```
Dim conStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblSubscribers", conStr)
Dim dataset As DataSet = New DataSet

adapter.Fill(dataset)

ListBoxSubscribers.DataSource = dataset.Tables(0)
ListBoxSubscribers.DisplayMember = "Phone"
ListBoxSubscribers.ValueMember = "Phone"
```

I am trying to iterate through each value of my listbox. The problem is I get P, h, o, n, e instead of the actual number. Here is my iteration program:

```
        For Each item As String In ListBoxSubscribers.ValueMember
            Dim PhoneNumber As String = item.ToString
            TextBoxPhoneNumberDisplay.Text = PhoneNumber
            SendSMS(PhoneNumber, msg)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Next
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx), I'm pretty sure valuemember and displaymember can only be properties of the class you're working with, in this case the DataSet class.

Answer (score 0):

the valuemember must be the primary key, by the way your not iterating through the whole valueMembers, its just the "string" set in that control, try setting the displayMember and ValueMember to columns in your dataset, like:

```
listboxsubscribers.displayMember = dataset.Tables(0).columns(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListBoxSubscribers` control is using a DataTable as its `DataSource`, which means the items in your list are DataRowView items, not strings.

You also iterate through the `Items` collection, not the `ValueMember` property.

Quick fix:

```
For Each item As DataRowView In ListBoxSubscribers.Items
  Dim PhoneNumber As String = item("Phone").ToString
  '\\ etc
Next
```